# Two Directives requesting isolated scope and inherited scope on the same element

Tags: angularjs

I have declared two directives on an element: one requesting isolated scope and the other requesting inherited scope. Here is:

**The Code**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            users: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "users-info.html",
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.title = "From My Directive";
        }
    }
})
.directive("otherDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.title = "From Other Directive";
        }
    };
})
.controller("AppController", function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {name: "Anup Vasudeva", username: "anup_vasudeva"},
        {name: "Ajay Sharma", username: "ajay_sharma"},
        {name: "Vinay Kumar", username: "vinay_kumar"}
    ];
    $scope.title = "Users Information";
});
```

**and the HTML**

```
<div my-directive other-directive>{{title}}</div>
```

But AngularJS is throwing error mentioning the URL:

```
http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir
```

But in the description of errors, I don't see a point where it says that multiple directives requesting isolated and inherited scope is not allowed.

** EDIT **
That seems strange, when I used angular `v1.2.0-rc.2`, the above scenario works fine. The `otherDirective` gets an isolated scope even if it asks for the shared scope. But this scenario doesn't works in the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because both of your directives are requesting an isolated scope.

To resolve this, set the scope option to false on the directive you want no isolated scope on:

```
app.directive("otherDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.title = "From Other Directive";
        }
    };
});
```

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24Pyg/)

Actually, you can omit the scope property for the same effect as well.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Is it possible for the otherDirective to have the inherited scope? I want otherDirective to have access to the "users" model

Comment: It does have the inherited scope. See my updated fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/24Pyg/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/24Pyg/1/). The title on otherDirective's scope comes from its parent controller.

Comment: from what I see, the otherDirective is having a shared scope, not an inherited one. Correct me if I am wrong. My concern is why an error when otherDirective is requesting an inherited scope.

Comment: in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24Pyg/2/) we try to access the title property in both directives. As you can see, otherDirective inherits (I think what you mean by share) the parent's scope and can access the title property on the scope. On the other hand, myDirective gets an isolated scope and the title property is undefined when we try to use it. Directives will get an inherited scope unless you explicitly create an isolated scope.

Comment: From what I know, and as per [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), only `scope: { ... }` creates an isolate scope. `scope: true` doesn't create an isolated scope, it just creates an inherited scope

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS allows only one isolated scope per element. If either if you do

```
scope: true
```

or

```
scope: {/* something */}
```

inside two directives on the same element, that just means you're requesting two isolated scopes on the same element.

Try with

```
scope: false
```

in `otherDirective`

Comment: Thanks @Ashesh: What I believe that even though the otherDirective is requesting the inherited scope, the isolated scope will be shared among myDirective and otherDirective. What my concern is, atleast AngularJS should not throw any error

Comment: @AnupVasudeva it throws an error only because an isolated scope on a single element doesn't really make life easy. :-) I find that perfectly reasonable. One element, conceptually, corresponds to a maximum of one isolated scope in Angular terms. Suppose you have two variables with the same name in two or more scopes and in that scenario, you have the two scopes on the same element. How do you think we'll resolve that situation?

Comment: Looking here, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md I don't see any scope related changes for the version you're talking about.

Comment: From what I know, `scope: true` doesn't create an isolated scope, it just creates an inherited scope